# Problems casting in a foreach

Tags: c#, casting

I'm having some problems with this section of code, it's from a little program I'm working for a magic item creator for an RPG.  It should be simple, the spellList (declared globally) is a Hashtable key of Strings, values are objects of class 'Spells'.

```
public void PopulateSpellDropDown()
{
    Spells s = new Spells();

    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in spellList)
    {
        s = entry.Value; **<- Error here, no implicit conversion.**
        cbScrollSpells.Items.Add(entry.Key.ToString());
    }
}
```

I've tried putting casts in all the places I can think of, but nothing seems to work.  I've tried searching some tutorials, but none of the suggestions seem to work.  I'm sure that this will be an embarrassingly simple problem but I would appreciate assistance.

Thank you.

Comment: can you provide the **error message** ???

Comment: What type `spellList` have?

Comment: Why aren't you using a Dictionary instead of Hashtable?

Comment: how about `s = (Spells)entry.Value`

Comment: `entry.Value` is of type object so you'll need to put a cast in there somewhere. You're trying to assign it to `s` which is of type `Spells` so if the obvious `(Spells)` doesn't work then your value is clearly not of type `Spells` in the first place in which case we can't help without more code.

Comment: Why did I have it my head I needed to cast with brackets like these <>?

Comment: @GáborBakos Habit mostly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When "values are objects of class 'Spells'", 
then this should work:

```
  s = (Spells) entry.Value;
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be simple, this worked great.  I had tried
s = <Spells>entry.Value;

Answer (score 3):

Just do this:

```
s = (Spell) entry.Value;
```

Alternatively, you can use a `Dictionary<T,T>` generic type as your collection, then you won't have to do any casting.

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly cast entry.Value to the proper type, like this:

```
(Spell)entry.Value
```

Also I'd rather use shorter

```
foreach (var entry in spellList)
```

instead of

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in spellList)
```

Comment: `as Spell` would not be my first choice. IF you know that it should really be of type Spell then using `as` will just mask an error if it is of the wrong type for some reason (as in it will most likely throw a null reference exception at some place down the line rather than throwing where the error actually is.

Comment: Fair comment, maybe I should think about casts in C# once more.

Comment: Sometimes you learn more when answering rather than asking :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. For what its worth I usually reserve `as` for when you have a type and you want to do something with it if it is of a specific subtype. Then you can cast using `as` and check for nullity. Though of course sometimes when doing this you've got to ask whether you are better off with a virtual method that can be overridden on those subtypes to give you the behaviour you want... :)

Answer (score 1):

If the value property on entry is of type `Spells` then an explicit cast will do the trick for you;

```
s = (Spells)entry.Value;
```